# How to place a div on the right side with absolute position

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I've a page where a dynamic message box has to be displayed without disturbing the actual page. This message box has to appear at the top right corner of the page overlapping the existing contents.

I've tried to use `position: absolute` but then I'm unable to place it in the right corner. Also I'm unable to use `left` since I've to support responsive design from Bootstrap.

Here is a sample markup

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Need to place this div at the top right of the page-->
            <div class="ajax-message">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span9">
                        <div class="alert">
                            <a class="close icon icon-remove"></a>
                            <div class="message-content">
                                Some message goes here
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Page contents starts here. These are dynamic-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12 inner-col">
                    <h2>Documents</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This message box should have a width of `50%` with respect to the `.container` and the left side of the message box should not be overlapped by it. ie we should be able to click/select the contents of the left side.

Please find a sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f9hKE/).

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333624/css-float-right-and-position-absolute-doesnt-work-together

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
yourbox{
   position:absolute;
   right:<x>px;
   top  :<x>px;
}
```

positions it in the right corner. Note, that the position is dependent of the first ancestor-element which is not `static` positioned!

EDIT:

[I updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/f9hKE/2/).

Answer (score 65):

```
yourbox {
   position: absolute;
   left: 100%;
   top: 0;
}
```

**left:100%;** is the important issue here!

Comment: `left:100%` puts the LEFT edge of the div at the far right side of the window, so the rest of the div is hidden. `left:94%` worked for me. Great solution, thanks.

Comment: This assumes that `yourbox` is 100% of the window width

Comment: While `left: 100%` is not always what you would want, in my case, it was perfect, as it positioned the *left* edge of the div relative to the *right* edge of its container.

Answer (score 40):

For top right corner try this:

```css
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use "**translateX**"

```
<div class="box">
<div class="absolute-right"></div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.box{
    text-align: right;
}
.absolute-right{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}

/*The magic:*/
.absolute-right{
-moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
-ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
-o-transform: translateX(-100%);
transform: translateX(-100%);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple, use absolute positioning, and instead of specifying a top and a left, specify a top and a right!

For example:

```
#logo_image {
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    top:10px;
    right:10px;
    z-index: 3;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: (－‸ლ) That works. ([MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right) for the doubters)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your container element is probably `position:relative;`. This is will mean that the dialog box will be positioned accordingly to the container, not the page.

Can you change the markup to this?

```
<html>
<body>
    <!-- Need to place this div at the top right of the page-->
        <div class="ajax-message">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span9">
                    <div class="alert">
                        <a class="close icon icon-remove"></a>
                        <div class="message-content">
                            Some message goes here
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Page contents starts here. These are dynamic-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12 inner-col">
                <h2>Documents</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

With the dialog box outside the main container then you can use absolute positioning relative to the page.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me:

```
.yourbox {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;  
    right: 0;
    left: inherit;
}
```

It is important here - **left: inherit;**

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
float: right;
```