# Menu left and menu right

Tags: css, menu, alignment

Trying to have 2 menus one at the left and one at the right but cant really complete this tasks since my right menu is going to the left, my css file

```
body
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    background: #141414 url('/public/images/background/body_bg.png') top left repeat;
    font: 12px Tahoma,Arial,Hevetica,Sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.left-menu, .right-menu
{
    position: absolute;

    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 197px;
    width: 128px;
    max-width: 128px;
}

.left-menu ul, .right-menu ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.left-menu ul li.header, .right-menu ul li.header
{
    line-height: 29px;
    height: 29px;
    color: white;
    background-image: url('/public/images/background/head.jpg');
    font: 15px 'Trebuchet MS',Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    padding: 6px 0 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;

}

.left-menu ul li a, .right-menu ul li a
{
    background: #CD0000;
    background: rgb(0,0,0);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000,endColorstr=#99000000);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-top: 0px;
    height: 14px;
    padding: 4px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 14px;
}

.left-menu ul li a:hover, .right-menu ul li a:hover
{
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

a:visited 
{
    color: #ffcc00;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a
{
    color: #ffcc00;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.title
{
    position: static;
    background: url('/public/images/background/title.jpg');
    height: 35px;
    color: white;
    font: 15px 'Trebuchet MS',Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-top: 0;
    line-height: 35px;
    background-image: url('/public/images/background/title.jpg');
    background-position: left;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    margin-left: 140px;
    margin-right: 140px;
    text-align: center;
}

#header
{
    align: middle;
    position: static;
    height: 183px;
    max-height: 183px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

table.hovertable
{
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #BDBDBD;
}

table.hovertable td
{
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: black;
    height: 181px;
    max-height: 181px;
    text-align: center;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #290008;
}
```

And my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::to('/') }}/style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <TITLE>PokemonGarden - Online Pokemon RPG</TITLE>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
      <div class="header">
      <center>
      <table align="center" class="hovertable">
      <tbody><tr>
      <td><img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/background/pball.png"><br><b>Empty Slot</b></td>
      <td><img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/background/pball.png"><br><b>Empty Slot</b></td>
      <td><img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/background/pball.png"><br><b>Empty Slot</b></td>
      <td><img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/background/pball.png"><br><b>Empty Slot</b></td>
      <td><img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/background/pball.png"><br><b>Empty Slot</b></td>
      <td><img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/background/pball.png"><br><b>Empty Slot</b></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody></table>
      </center>
      </div>
      <div class="left-menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="header">Main menu</li>
            <li><a href="profile.php">Homepage</a></li>
            <li><a href="profile.php">Homepage</a></li>
            <li><a href="profile.php">Homepage</a></li>
            <li><a href="profile.php">Homepage</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="title">Players Online - Past 5 minutes</div>
      <div class="right-menu">
         <ul>
            <li class="header">Main menu</li>
            <li><a href="profile.php">Homepage</a></li>
            <li><a href="profile.php">Homepage</a></li>
            <li><a href="profile.php">Homepage</a></li>
            <li><a href="profile.php">Homepage</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

The current design should be

1ST MENU -- DIV WITH TEXT -- 2ND MENU

But my 2ND Menu is going to the same place of the 1ST MENU.

Comment: have you tried float left on the left menu and float right on the right menu?

Comment: Yes, and did not work.

Comment: put this into a jsfiddle or equivalent so we can look at a live example

Comment: Maybe float:left; on the left menu and float:right; on the right menu and overflow: hidden; on the parent.

Comment: I believe the float will not work if position is set to absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using absolute positioning for the layout. So, you need to specify the left/right carefully. If you omit, it picks up the left by default.

Just add this to your css:

```
.right-menu { right: 0px; }
```

Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m4j2v/

Answer (score 1):

try this in your css:

```
.left-menu, .right-menu
{
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        top: 197px;
        width: 128px;
        max-width: 128px;
}
.left-menu{
       float:left;
}
.right-menu{
       float:right;
}
```

alternatively look at the following post: [Float right and position absolute doesn't work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333624/css-float-right-and-position-absolute-doesnt-work-together)