# Why is float:right making the div float to the left?

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS. I'm trying to position a div (#inner) in the bottom-right corner of another div (#container).
I wrote `float: right;` but when running the Html I see the inner div in the bottom-**left** corner of the container. Why is that? What's wrong with the code?

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  border: solid;
  width: 70%;
  height: 40%;
}
#inner {
  position: absolute;
  border: solid;
  bottom: 0;
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="inner">
    ABC
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `float` with absolute positioning doesn't really make sense. I think what you want is `right:0` instead of `float:right`

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  border: solid;
  width: 70%;
  height: 40%;
  overflow: auto;
}
#inner {
  position: absolute;
  border: solid;
  bottom: 0;
  right:0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="inner">
    ABC
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is some useful documentation about positioning, you should take a look. 
http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: This works. But can you please explain why using float doesn't make sense when using position : absolute ?

Comment: The second answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333624/float-right-and-position-absolute-doesnt-work-together sheds light on why

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the absolute position. Also, if you want the container to wrap the float/s, add "overflow: auto" to the container element:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  border: solid;
  width: 70%;
  height: 40%;
  overflow: auto;
}
#inner {
  border: solid;
  bottom: 0;
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="inner">
    ABC
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately with this solution the inner div is in the top-right corner and not in the bottom-right

Comment: in this case don't use float at all, but only absolute position.

Answer (score 1):

you must remove "position: absolute"